# Spring boot : load profile specific application.properties from file system

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I am trying to load external properties files based on the current active profile

and the properties files I have defined  as below :

```
default -> resources/config/application.properties (for dev)
qa -> c:\external-configuration\config\application-qa.properties
prod -> c:\external-configuration\config\application-prod.properties
```

how spring can be configured to read all these `application*.properties` from different sources?

I tried to define a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as below but spring could resolve the properties value based on the active profile, I always get the default values defined in `application.properties`

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("c:\external-configuration\config\application-qa.properties"),new FileSystemResource("c:\external-configuration\config\application-prod.properties"));
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: so all of the configurations have different key-> value?, if so, why not merge into one property file, if they have same key, you should do it by yourself

Comment: Can you set 'spring.profiles.active=dev, qa, etc' in 'application.properties' or when you run jar then set command line argument t load specific property 'java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

Comment: Yeah, when I run the jar file with -Dspring.profiles.active=qa option I still get the values defined in the application.properties not in application-qa.properties as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First specify which profile you want to load with `spring.profiles.active`. Secondly, as it isn't one of the default locations, add `spring.config.additional-location` to add additional locations to scan. So when you start your line should look like

```
java -jar <your-jar>.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.additional-location=file:C:/external-configuration/config/
```

This is also documented in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

And remove your custom `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as that isn't needed.

Comment: that's very neat solution, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use java annotation for property resource and use server environment (active profile) to identify which properties file to load.

Like, this code snippet here, it will look for property 'envTarget' and in case its not found or null, it will use default 'qa':

```
@PropertySource({ 
  "classpath:application-${envTarget:qa}.properties"
})
```